# LAST_INSERT_ID remain same without increment

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables named fullview,dimTab and factTab.I want to insert data from fullview to other two tables using stored procedure.Primary key of dimTab table should insert as a column value for factTab table.I have tried below procedure but all the rows of foreign key are remained as same without increment.Highly appreciate your help.

[Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1bjj.png)

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE tranxdata6()
BEGIN
DECLARE out_param INTEGER;
INSERT INTO dimTab (itm_no,itm_type) SELECT itm_no,itm_type from  fullview; 
SET out_param = LAST_INSERT_ID() ;
INSERT INTO factTab (id,name,company,itm_key) SELECT f.id,f.name,f.company,out_param from fullview as f;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfSU7.png)

Comment: You are going to need to do this using a loop.  Of course all get the same id -- you are only setting the id once and then passing that value into the `insert`.  An alternative would be to use a trigger on `factTab`.

Comment: Could you please post the stored procedure adding loop

Comment: I have solved it using a loop.Thank you @GordonLinoff for your support.